# Measure disk IO latencies of a running process

Tags: linux, strace, perf-event, dtrace

I'm trying to measure the disk IO latencies of a running process to make a histogram.

I could do this with DTrace in operating systems that provide it (e.g. as in [this Joyent paper](http://joyent.com/content/05-developers/01-resources/15-examining-file-system-latency-in-production/examining-file-system-latency.pdf)), but my application is running in Linux. My first thought was to try `perf`, and I can get counters but I can't find any way to get time deltas. I can get time deltas with `strace` (e.g. `strace -e read -T`), but I'm not sure if I can restrict the trace to disk IO (this system has a busy network interface as well).

Is there any way to do this in Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually complicated. But there is hints:

- Learn about SystemTap, this is linux analog of DTrace. I think they may even have example script for similar task.
- Learn [blktrace](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~aaronc/iosched/doc/blktrace.html). You may be able to parse its output, in theory. This will be more device latency (service time) than *response time* program get on `read()`.

Yes `strace` may not be appropriate, since it will trace everything (all syscalls, even when you use `-e` filter) and will load server and slower process considerably. `Perf` is very obscure tool, you may have moments you think you understand its output, but you actually didn't, and its feature set is highly depend on kernel version. Basically and currently `perf` is suitable for measuring *CPU time* (cycles), and [yet] unsuitable to measuring *reponse times* (which you actually need). I heard they wanted to implement something to ease that, so on very recent development kernels there may have something. (Look also in perf-scripts (`perf script -l`) if you will investigate further.)

- May be you will be able to get something from *ftrace*. Read this article http://lwn.net/Articles/370423/ (And this for the [intro](http://lwn.net/Articles/322666/).) As I can see you can limit ftracing by `pid` and function, then trace with something like `sys_read`. I tried this as example for you:

  ```
  # mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug # if it's not already mounted
  # cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
  # echo $$ > set_ftrace_pid  # pid of process to trace
  # echo sys_read sys_write > set_ftrace_filter
  # echo function_graph > current_tracer
  # head trace

  # tracer: function_graph
  #
  # CPU  DURATION                  FUNCTION CALLS
  # |     |   |                     |   |   |   |
   0)   8.235 us    |  sys_write();
   0)   3.393 us    |  sys_write();
   0) ! 459859.3 us |  sys_read();
   0)   6.289 us    |  sys_write();
   0)   8.773 us    |  sys_write();
   0) ! 1576469 us |  sys_read();
  ```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there are several options in there. I started with blktrace, which seems like it's supposed to do what I want, but I couldn't get the -t option to work. I will look at the others as well.

Comment: Interesting approach there http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-01/perf-heat-maps.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in the number of "read" or "write" calls to block devices [this is Red Hat's SOP for determining that](http://dpaste.org/BhZSu/).

> Using the block dump feature and a bit of scripting a high level
>   overview about the I/O actions processes are producing can be
>   gathered. To do so, complete the following:
>
> Disable system logging for a short period of time (so it doesn't get
>   in the way of the data capture):
>
> # service syslog stop  # echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump
>
> Wait for the high iowait issue to occur, once it has past re-enable
>   syslog (or rsyslog if using that), and disable the block dump:
>
> # service syslog start  # echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump
>
> Using the following command parse the dmesg output for
>   READ/WRITE/dirtied actions being issued by certain processes:
>
> # dmesg | awk '/(READ|WRITE|dirtied)/ {activity[$1]++} END {for (x in
>   activity) print x, activity[x]}'| sort -nr -k 2,2| head -n 10
>
> kjournald(1425): 5984
>    kjournald(3681): 1269
>    pdflush(27301): 725 
>    iostat(2913): 134
>    crond(26919): 61
>    crond(28985): 60
>    crond(7026): 54
>    sshd(28175): 50
>    sshd(15388): 50
>    nautilus(24498): 46
>
> The example output above shows the top 10 processes that issued READ,
>   WRITE and dirtied operations during the time the block dump was
>   running. Using this data a high level overview of the number of
>   operations processes are issuing can be gathered and it can help
>   determine if a single process is contributing highly to iowait.

There are also several command line tools like atop and iotop that give you per-process iowait statistics and can be ran as part of a script (meaning they have batch modes that can do a single iteration for particular PIDs).

---

**EDIT:**
Doing more research it looks like you can [get per-process iowait from /proc/$pid/stat](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) (search for "Aggregated block I/O delays")

Comment: It looks like neither of those will get me enough information to make a histogram. I'm specifically interested in the wait time distribution, rather than the aggregate wait time.

Comment: /proc/pid/stat should still help, you would just need a script to run periodically and record the information, subtracting the value that was found last time. After that you're pretty much taking about sample rate.